# Group sql with rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle

If I wanted to display my object in a some hierarchy like display and if my object had properties like this :

parent_id, property_id, name

And I wanted to display it like this:

```
Parent
  -> Property
    -> Object name
```

So group them by parent first than by property, is this something I could do with the [group](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group)

I've never done this before, I have a solution with ruby, but I'm not sure if this could be done faster with database.

Or maybe I'm looking this in a wrong way, how can I do this kind of sorting/nesting when all the information needed is on my object. Sure the ids are there which point to the records holding the information.

**Update:**

Here is my take on this :

```
MyObj.group_by{|m| m.parent.parent_name}
     .map{|k,v| { k => v.group_by(&:property).sort_by{|prop_array| prop_array.first.display_order } }}
```

It's hideous, it's unreadable, sometimes even I wonder what I've been trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, you might want to consider using a gem for this: https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree

Comment: please see my update I think this might be it, I'm trying now. If you could think of something else please do post. thanks

Comment: actually no this does not work for me, it requires me to add an extra column to every model I would want to lookup in the tree

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty standard activerecord pattern. Offhand I don't see any reason to drop into sql. .group or .join should work fine. If you post more descriptive code I will try to be more specific. Play around with the existing data in the rails console to see what's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use ActiveRecord `group` for this, because `group` requires an aggregate function (like `count`, `max`, etc). What you are doing here is not an aggregate, you want to collect each and every object. If you would want to collect only counts, you could do this: `Object.group(:parent_id, :property_id).count`.

You can use `sort` to get the DB to do the sorting for you: `Object.sort(:parent_id, :property_id)`. Then you can iterate and group them by in one linear array pass. This will likely be faster, but not really any less code.

Comment: thanks for the response. I'm not looking to do it with less code, as long as it's readable and faster too than great!